# Graylog Cluster/Load Balance

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog2, graylog

How to do proper graylog 2.2.x cluster? Please Advice

I couldn't find any good solution for the graylog cluster or graylog load balance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Graylog documentation](http://docs.graylog.org/) has an extensive chapter on this: [Multi-node Setup](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.2/pages/configuration/multinode_setup.html)

Comment: Thanks and i think i have to go thru the document again. My concern was how to make graylog cluster/load balance in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Graylogs documentation will show you the direction but not that extensive especially if you are not an experienced admin.
I am trying to use nginx as load balancer. I tried it with rsyslog and it worked really good but rsyslog was not the answer for my needs so I am trying to discover how to do it over nginx with filebeat.

So here is my nginx.conf :

```
stream{
upstream graylog_servers {
    server 8.2.1.1:8000;
    server 8.2.1.2:8000;
    server 8.2.1.3:8000;
}
 server {
 listen 8000;
proxy_pass graylog_servers;
}
}
```

This way my filebeats can send data to 8000 port and I have my load balancing

Comment: *Graylogs documentation will show you the direction* is hardly an answer. Can you extend the answer with more details?

Comment: I will try with this method then.tq